# Bootstrap Carousel: Programmatically Set Image in Carousel with Animations

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a carousel with an accompanying thumbnail gallery.  I'd like to be able to set the image in the carousel when the user clicks on an image in the thumbnail gallery.  I got this to work by setting the appropriate item to "active", but it doesn't use any of the bootstrap transitions, so the image appears abruptly.  Is there any way for me to add in slide animations?

**Carousel (on left) with thumbnail gallery (on right):**
[image]

**javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // go to image in carousel
        function setCarousel(carouselID, image){
          $('.carousel.'+carouselID+' .item.active').removeClass('active');
          $('.carousel.'+carouselID + ' div:nth-child('+image+')').addClass('active');
        }

        // set photo to active in carousel when thumbnail is clicked
        $('.thumbGallery img').click(function(){
          var parent = $(this).attr("data-parent");
          var position = parseInt($(this).attr("data-position"))+1;
          console.log("parent: " + parent);
          console.log("position: " + position);

          // slide to the element in the slideshow
          setCarousel(parent, position);

        });    
</script>
```

**carousel html:**

```
<div id="detailViewPhoto">
       <div class="mainPhoto carousel slide 523" id="carousel-523">
           <div class="carousel-inner 523 active">
                <div class="item active">       
                    <a class="fancybox" href="https://buildinprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/image/imagePath/897/2013-06-18_08.25.02.jpg" rel="gallery 523"> 
                     <img alt="Preview_2013-06-18_08.25.02" src="https://buildinprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/image/imagePath/897/preview_2013-06-18_08.25.02.jpg" width="100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                   <a class="fancybox" href="https://buildinprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/image/imagePath/898/2013-06-18_08.24.07.jpg" rel="gallery 523"> 
                   <img alt="Preview_2013-06-18_08.24.07" src="https://buildinprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/image/imagePath/898/preview_2013-06-18_08.24.07.jpg" width="100%">
                   </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel-523" data-slide="prev" style="display: none;">‹</a>
             <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel-523" data-slide="next" style="display: none;">›</a>
       </div>

       <div class="thumbGallery 523">
          <img alt="Thumb_2013-06-18_08.25.02" data-parent="523" data-position="0" src="https://buildinprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/image/imagePath/897/thumb_2013-06-18_08.25.02.jpg" style="padding: 4px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); max-width: 85%; cursor: default;">
         <img alt="Thumb_2013-06-18_08.24.07" data-parent="523" data-position="1" src="https://buildinprogress.s3.amazonaws.com/image/imagePath/898/thumb_2013-06-18_08.24.07.jpg" style="padding: 4px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); max-width: 85%; cursor: default;">
       </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there's a default carousel method for doing this.  It's $('.carousel').carousel(number) where number is the item you want to cycle to.  Doh!